# PostgreSQL DB changes time when I import data from CSV-file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

I have a [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8lJM.png%5D) of table with datetime attribute like '2016-04-03T00:00:00', when I copy this CSV to my PostgreSQL table it changes time to ['2016-04-02 21:00:00+00'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKZBV.png) (I have timestamp with tz in this table cause table attribute of timestamp is created by Django DateTimeField which can only have timestamp with timezone), how to avoid time change and to get timestamp in PostgreSQL like ''2016-04-02 00:00:00+00' after copying.
Added screen of my CSV and table result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apparently your timezone setting differs between the connection which does COPY and the one that selects the data back.

Comment: Since `2016-04-03T00:00:00` has a `T` in this format, it indicates that this datetime has a time zone. So, during inserting process dates will be changes using your server time zone

Comment: In what client are you viewing the output? What does the data look like when you use the command line client `psql` to view it? What does `show timezone;` return in the Postgres server?

Comment: @RaminFaracov, `T` does not mean timezone. Per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):"ISO 8601 uses the 24-hour clock system. As of ISO 8601-1:2019, the basic format is T[hh][mm][ss] and the extended format is T[hh]:[mm]:[ss]. Earlier versions omitted the T (representing time) in both formats. " Tz is represented at end of string with `Z` or `+-` numeric offset. See link for more information.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, you are right.

Comment: @jjanes yes, I think so, but I don't know how to set timezone=utc paratameter when I use COPY

Comment: You answered your own question, do `set timezone=utc;` before you do the COPY.  If your client won't let you, then you need to give us more information about that (or use a different client)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver so firstly I had Europe/Moscow, but than I set UTC as I want, but it doesn't help, because as I know time zone is a session parameter. So when I have timezone = Moscow/Europe (which is +3) I get datetime = '2016-04-02 00:00:00+3' , when I set timezone = 'UTC' I get datetime = ['2016-04-02 21:00:00+00'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKZBV.png) , but I need to get '2016-04-02 00:00:00+00', like my [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8lJM.png%5D)

Comment: @jjanes I've deleted all data from my db, set timezone=utc in psql, set timezone=utc in pgadmin, after that make an import from csv again and it doesn't work, still got 2016-04-02 21:00:00+00 instead of 2016-04-03 00:00:00+00 (in my csv file 2016-04-03T00:00:00)

Comment: @jjanes That’s what I have
[psql tz](https://imgur.com/U9PPce9),
[pgadmin tz](https://imgur.com/bSQzXcs),
[csv file](https://imgur.com/VJKVgWJ),
[pgadmin table](https://imgur.com/qerICpt)

Comment: If the COPY is being done in django (which is how you tagged your question) then of course changing the session setting of some other session being used in psql or pgadmin won't do anything.

Comment: @jjanes no, no, table is done by Django model, but copy is being made by my own python script which is connecting to db, which Django project uses

Comment: @jjanes I just tried to make a new db and table which is not connected to Django project and I finally got what I want after copying = 2016-04-03 00:00:00+00, but what to do to stop django to change the format

Comment: **DO NOT use images** to present textual data. Also do not add relevant information/data in the comments. Copy and paste the data as update to question.